# Chrome UserAgent network condition not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, user-agent

I've been using Chrome Debugger since forever to test my site's mobile layout. I click the mobile icon in the top left corner and then refresh the page. It updates the User Agent string and it's all good. Last week it started doing this weird behavior where it changes it to this after a page refresh:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
```

When I click the mobile icon in the Chrome Debugger then it immediately reports the correct user agent. But when I refresh the browser it reverts to the non-mobile user agent listed above and stays there. Note that the browser still shows the page dimensions correctly as being a mobile device, so it does know that I clicked the mobile button, but the user agent doesn't match up anymore.

I have to toggle it off and back on using the Debugger and then it only works until I refresh the page. So it temporarily sets it to the correct user agent string but always loses it on a page refresh. If I click the refresh button enough times it does show the correct user agent, but on the next refresh it immediately goes back to the non-mobile user agent. I'm guessing it's correct about ten percent of the time.

I use the site https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent  to test the current setting.

Any ideas?

Thanks.